# Best way to extract the minimum and maximum value of the dense part of a distribution?

Tags: algorithm

I have a distributions of point distance to a parallel line. Each distributions have an area more populated which represent the point channel. I would like to extract the minimum and maximum represented by the red line in the graphs? The eyes can do it easily but how to do it robustly with an algorithm?

The x axis represents the perpendicular distance of the points to the line from 0 to 100m.

The y axis represents the number of points that have their distance in a certain bin.

*Example 1*

[image: Find boundaries]

*Example 2*

[image: Find boundaries]

Comment: What do you know about the distribution?

Comment: That's a good point, I modified the description, thanks

Comment: Take a look to my update.

Answer (score 1):

Since the distribution comes from a set of distances from points to a line, and the values are in order, you may try to compute the normal distribution that models your samples. From there, get as margins (your red bars) the mean +/- x*sigma, where x can be the value you want (maybe 1 or 2).

If the points were not in order, you may get some percentile (0.25, for example) of the full list of values as a threshold, and assume your populated part of the distribution starts there for values higher than that percentile.

Comment: The mean is shifted in both cases because of the skewness of the data towards one side. It will probably offset the red lines by using mean +/- x*sigma.
If I use the percentile option, The error on the red lines will probably be too big.
Maybe another option is to filter the graph with a low pass filter and then try to find the red lines as the rising edge?